# Simple C# Evernote API OAuth example or guide?

Tags: c#, oauth, evernote

Anybody know where I can find a simple example C# code example? Apparently really tough to find.

I'm just starting out, got my Developer key.

Initial (really noob question/presumption) - -Can (should/must) my solution be a web service client? No new libraries I need to install in .Net right?

Basically, as a test, I want to be able to securely present a single note from a private notebook in html similar to what the Everfort export in html looks like on a outside WebSite.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

You should start by downloading our API ZIP from http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/. You'll find C# client sample code in /sample/csharp. This sample code demonstrates using the Evernote API from a desktop application that authenticates using username and password.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you ever got this working, but I was playing around with Evernote, OpenAuth and C# this morning and managed to get it all working. I have put together a blog post / library explaining the experience and outlining how to do it with MVC here - http://www.shaunmccarthy.com/evernote-oauth-csharp/ - it uses the AsyncOAuth library: https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth

I wrote a wrapper around AsyncOAuth that you might find useful here: https://github.com/shaunmccarthy/AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple

One prickly thing to be aware of - the Evernote Endpoints (/oauth and /OAuth.action) are case sensitive

```
// Download the library from https://github.com/shaunmccarthy/AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple

// Configure the Authorizer with the URL of the Evernote service,
// your key, and your secret. 
var EvernoteAuthorizer = new EvernoteAuthorizer(
    "https://sandbox.evernote.com", 
    "slyrp-1234", // Not my real id / secret :)
    "7acafe123456badb123");

// First of all, get a request token from Evernote - this causes a 
// webrequest from your server to Evernote.
// The callBackUrl is the URL you want the user to return to once
// they validate the app
var requestToken = EvernoteAuthorizer.GetRequestToken(callBackUrl);

// Persist this token, as we are going to redirect the user to 
// Evernote to Authorize this app
Session["RequestToken"] = requestToken;

// Generate the Evernote URL that we will redirect the user to in
// order to 
var callForwardUrl = EvernoteAuthorizer.BuildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken);

// Redirect the user (e.g. MVC)
return Redirect(callForwardUrl);

// ... Once the user authroizes the app, they get redirected to callBackUrl

// where we parse the request parameter oauth_validator and finally get
// our credentials
// null = they didn't authorize us
var credentials = EvernoteAuthorizer.ParseAccessToken(
    Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"], 
    Session["RequestToken"] as RequestToken);

// Example of how to use the credential with Evernote SDK
var noteStoreUrl = EvernoteCredentials.NotebookUrl;
var noteStoreTransport = new THttpClient(new Uri(noteStoreUrl));
var noteStoreProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(noteStoreTransport);
var noteStore = new NoteStore.Client(noteStoreProtocol);
List<Notebook> notebooks = client.listNotebooks(EvernoteCredentials.AuthToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2010/08/06/edamlibrary-evernote-library-for-c.aspx might help.  As the author states it just bundles some and fixes some.  Haven't tried it myself but thought I'd mention for a possibly easier way to get started.  Possibly.

Answer (score 0):

This might help too...found it using the Way Back Machine since the original blog site was offline.

https://www.evernote.com/pub/bluecockatoo/Evernote_API#b=bb2451c9-b5ff-49bb-9686-2144d984c6ba&n=c30bc4eb-cca4-4a36-ad44-1e255eeb26dd

The original blog post: http://web.archive.org/web/20090203134615/http://macrolinz.com/macrolinz/index.php/2008/12/

Scroll down and find the post from December 26 - "Get it while it's hot..."