# Evernote AuthToken via OAuth

Tags: c#, api, oauth, evernote

I have worked with OAuth before (working with Twitter and PHP) and it was simple.  I am trying to get OAuth to work with the EverNote API sample https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-csharp (because, as they say, "Real applications authenticate with Evernote using OAuth").  I looked at these:

[Simple C# Evernote API OAuth example or guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794245/simple-c-sharp-evernote-api-oauth-example-or-guide)

https://github.com/sethhitch/csharp-oauth-sample

http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/

But, I still don't know how to do this...  This is my code:

```
    // Real applications authenticate with Evernote using OAuth, but for the
    // purpose of exploring the API, you can get a developer token that allows
    // you to access your own Evernote account. To get a developer token, visit 
    // https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action
    String authToken = "myAuthCode";

    if (authToken == "your developer token") {
      Console.WriteLine("Please fill in your developer token");
      Console.WriteLine("To get a developer token, visit https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action");
      return;
    }
```

How can I add OAuth to this to get my `authToken`?

Thank you.

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466757/code-for-oauth-for-evernote-in-wp7 and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794245/simple-c-sharp-evernote-api-oauth-example-or-guide

Comment: Thanks but those are two of the same links I already looked at (as posted above).

Comment: This particular script is what I am trying to understand https://github.com/sethhitch/csharp-oauth-sample/blob/master/Evernote.OAuth.Wp7/MainPage.xaml.cs  How can I implement that in my C# console application (the Evernote sample)?

Comment: can you be more specific please? which bit you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I see how there are button clicks and "onNavigating" in https://github.com/sethhitch/csharp-oauth-sample/blob/master/Evernote.OAuth.Wp7/MainPage.xaml.cs and I don't know how to apply those in my Console application.

Comment: ok first on your console app try to do the basic thing first : var authorizer = new OAuthAuthorizer(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret); and print out the result. Don't forget to add the evernote external reference to your project.

Comment: The first error that I get is that I am missing the "OAuthAuthorizer" namespace.  I see the "packages" folder contains a number of OAuth related files.  How can I add the namespace?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried adding the "packages" folder from https://github.com/sethhitch/csharp-oauth-sample to my project but VS 2010 can't find CodePlex when I use `using Codeplex.OAuth;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple code to add is:

```
EvernoteOAuth oauth = new EvernoteOAuth(EvernoteOAuth.HostService.Sandbox, myConsumerKey, myConsumerSecret);
        string errResponse = oauth.Authorize();
        if (errResponse.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Token: {0}\r\n\r\nExpires: {1}\r\n\r\nNoteStoreUrl: {2}\r\n\r\nUserId: {3}\r\n\r\nWebApiUrlPrefix: {4}", oauth.Token, oauth.Expires, oauth.NoteStoreUrl, oauth.UserId, oauth.WebApiUrlPrefix));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A problem has occurred in attempting to authorize the use of your Evernote account: " + errResponse);
        }
```

You will need to use this assembly:

```
using EvernoteOAuthNet;
```

Available here:

http://www32.zippyshare.com/v/98249023/file.html

Answer (score 7):

Check this sample project  : http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/30584-here-is-a-net-oauth-assembly/ . I think this will help you to understand how oauth works.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.  But, something weird is happening:  When I add `using EvernoteOAuthNet;` it appears with red underline, then I go to references -> add new reference, locate the `EvernoteOAuthNet.dll` file and add it.  Then the `using EvernoteOAuthNet;` appears fine, but when I build, it gets a red underline again and says, "The type or namespace name 'EvernoteOAuthNet' could not be found."

Comment: Your answer was what I used.  I found a solution to my problem of not being able to use the .DLL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143255/cant-load-assembly-dll-thats-visible-in-references

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to get this to work in MVC, I was playing around with Evernote, OpenAuth and C# this morning and managed to get it all working. I have put together a blog post / library explaining the experience and outlining how to do it with MVC here - http://www.shaunmccarthy.com/evernote-oauth-csharp/ - it uses the AsyncOAuth library: https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth

I wrote a wrapper around AsyncOAuth that you might find useful here: https://github.com/shaunmccarthy/AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple

One prickly thing to be aware of - the Evernote Endpoints (/oauth and /OAuth.action) are case sensitive

```
// Download the library from https://github.com/shaunmccarthy/AsyncOAuth.Evernote.Simple

// Configure the Authorizer with the URL of the Evernote service,
// your key, and your secret. 
var EvernoteAuthorizer = new EvernoteAuthorizer(
    "https://sandbox.evernote.com", 
    "slyrp-1234", // Not my real id / secret :)
    "7acafe123456badb123");

// First of all, get a request token from Evernote - this causes a 
// webrequest from your server to Evernote.
// The callBackUrl is the URL you want the user to return to once
// they validate the app
var requestToken = EvernoteAuthorizer.GetRequestToken(callBackUrl);

// Persist this token, as we are going to redirect the user to 
// Evernote to Authorize this app
Session["RequestToken"] = requestToken;

// Generate the Evernote URL that we will redirect the user to in
// order to 
var callForwardUrl = EvernoteAuthorizer.BuildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken);

// Redirect the user (e.g. MVC)
return Redirect(callForwardUrl);

// ... Once the user authroizes the app, they get redirected to callBackUrl

// where we parse the request parameter oauth_validator and finally get
// our credentials
// null = they didn't authorize us
var credentials = EvernoteAuthorizer.ParseAccessToken(
    Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"], 
    Session["RequestToken"] as RequestToken);

// Example of how to use the credential with Evernote SDK
var noteStoreUrl = EvernoteCredentials.NotebookUrl;
var noteStoreTransport = new THttpClient(new Uri(noteStoreUrl));
var noteStoreProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(noteStoreTransport);
var noteStore = new NoteStore.Client(noteStoreProtocol);
List<Notebook> notebooks = client.listNotebooks(EvernoteCredentials.AuthToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the OAuth library found here : https://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth and follow the steps mentioned [here](http://dev.evernote.com/start/core/authentication.php).