# Can't Load Assembly (.DLL) that's visible in References

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, oauth

As shown in the screenshot, VS 2010 is failing to load my OAuth reference despite the fact that it is RIGHT THERE in my References folder.  What am I doing wrong?  I have already restarted VS 2010.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was VS 2010 was deleting the assembly every time I would try to build.  I found the solution:

You need to change your target framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4"

Ref.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/1537c41b-52b9-4e47-91b2-2e38b8fdfbfa/

Answer (score 5):

An assembly (the DLL) does not *necessarily* need to use the same names for namespaces as the DLL name.  This means that your assembly (`EvernoteOAuthNet.dll`) may use a completely different namespace structure, ie: `Evernote.OAuth`.  You can double-click on the assembly in References to view it in the Object Browser, and inspect what types it contains, including their namespaces.  This may help you pick the right namespace for your `using` .

Comment: I don't see it in the object browser.  When I double-click the assembly in my Solution Explorer, it highlights C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Accessibility.dll.  I am using the same `using` statement that compiles properly as taken from here http://www.moreproductivenow.com/files/EvernoteOAuthNet.zip.  It just won't compile in *my* project...

Comment: I removed it, then added it again and I see it in the Object Browser when I double click it from References.  However, when I Build, it disappears from the Object Browser!  Any explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer below...  Thanks for your help.  Had you not have said that, I wouldn't have realized where the problem was.